# How to set filter.fn (param to read.matrix in R) so that it cleans row and column names to only contain alphanum plus dash and dot characters

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

I'm a lightweight when it comes to R and I'm trying to use a package called Seurat. I learned that non-10x sparse market matrix data (.mtx files) can be read in using read.matrix and that the row and column names can be loaded from the associated csv files.  However, the row and column names need to have specific characters (anything that's not alphanumeric, dot, or dash) removed.  I'd like to replace "bad characters" with dashes.  And I'd like to do this in R so that I can keep the disk space my deliverables take up small.

I was looking at the read.matrix help doc, and it looks like you can set a param called filter.fn (which I infer is a function, although that's not explicitly stated) in order to "clean" row and column names.

I learned how to create a function, and I got it to take row.ids and col.ids as arguments.  I learned how to use character classes to make substitutions in the strings contained there-in (and my tests show that it does what I want).  But since functions only return 1 value or set, I'm not sure what to return.  I tried returning `c(row.ids, col.ids)` but that creates a 1 dimensional set.  Even if I figure out how to return a 2D set, I'm not sure that's what's needed.  I tried to see if changes to the variables submitted persist, but they do not.  And I don't know what to search for to solve this.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
coldata <- read.csv(file="cell_metadata.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
colnames <- paste(coldata$cell_barcode)
rowdata <- read.csv(file="genes.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
rownames <- paste(rowdata$genome, rowdata$gene_id, rowdata$gene_name, sep = ".")

cleanrowscols <- function(row.ids, col.ids) {
  row.ids <- gsub("[^[:alnum:\\\\-\\\\.] ]", "-", row.ids)
  col.ids <- gsub("[^[:alnum:\\\\-\\\\.] ]", "-", col.ids)
  return(1)
}

read.matrix("DGE.mtx", header = TRUE, skip = 1, row.ids = rownames,
  col.ids = colnames, colClasses = c("numeric", "numeric", "numeric"),
  assign.fn = assign_matrix_dense, filter.fn = cleanrowscols)
```

But what does cleanrowscols have to return to get it to clean the row and column names supplied to read.matrix?

*UPDATE*: Ugh, R doesn't even know what read.matrix is and I don't know how to import it.  So perhaps a different tack.  I discovered that `library("Matrix")` has `readMM(file)`, so I tried `readMM("DGE.mtx")` and it seems to work.  How to I set the row and column names?

Answer (score 0):

OK.  I think I figured it out.

```
coldata <- read.csv(file="cell_metadata.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
colnames <- gsub("[^[:alnum:\\\\-\\\\.] ]", "-", paste(coldata$cell_barcode))

rowdata <- read.csv(file="genes.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
rownames <- gsub("[^[:alnum:\\\\-\\\\.] ]", "-", paste(rowdata$genome, rowdata$gene_id, rowdata$gene_name, sep = "."))

library("Matrix")
mtx <- t(as.matrix(readMM("DGE.mtx")))
rownames(mtx) <- rownames
colnames(mtx) <- colnames
```

Although, I'm sure there's a better, more efficient answer.  Note, I had to transpose, because seurate expects genes as rows and cells as columns.  I concatenated some data for the row names.  In fact, I need to figure out one more thing, but it's outside of the scope of this question.  (I need to add the chromosome to the row names, but it's not in the genes.csv file...)

Comment: I'll not select my own answer and wait for a better one.

Comment: I'm not sure why I had to have so many backslashes in the character class, but hey, it works.